# Running WebAssembly on Google Apps Script

Tags: asynchronous, google-apps-script, async-await, webassembly

I am attempting to run WebAssembly on the new V8 Google Apps Script runtime, and it appears to be supported, however it seems that async functions are terminated after they return a Promise.

```
let wasm= new Uint8Array([/* snip */]).buffer
function add(a,b) {
  return((async()=>{
  console.log("running function...")
  results=await WebAssembly.instantiate(wasm)
  return results.instance.exports.add(a,b)
})());
}
function test(){
  add(2,3).then(console.log).catch(console.error)
}
```

when I run `test` "running function..." is logged, then nothing. No errors, no results. I have confirmed that `WebAssembly.instantiate` returns a Promise.
Does anyone know what is going on, or is this something to ask Google about?

#### Update:

Created a issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153828715

Comment: Make sure your snip is a valid module. If so, Create a issue in issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: The exact code works in browsers too, so it is valid.

Comment: if you create a issue, link it here for wider reach

Comment: Issue is at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153828715

Comment: Issue marked as **Fixed**

Answer (score 4):

Asynchronous functionalities don't seem to be fully supported in V8 yet. There is actually an [open Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149937257) regarding this. You can click the star on the top left of the page to keep track of this issue.

In any case, please be aware that there is no explicit statement in [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#improved_function_detection) referring to the availability of these functionalities in V8. It just states that you can use keywords like `async` in your code, but it doesn't mention what functionality you will get if you use that.

#### Reference:

- [Issue Tracker: Async with V8 is not implemented as async / concurrent; documentation could be improved](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149937257)
- [V8 Runtime Overview: Improved function detection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#improved_function_detection)

Answer (score 4):

Refactored the sample script you provided on issue tracker and got it to work from the GAS editor (maybe Google changed something since you've posted this issue). GAS is synchronous but you can still use async/await as follows:

```js
async function testWasm() {
    let bytes = new Uint8Array([0,97,115,109,1,0,0,0,1,7,1,96,2,127,127,1,127,3,2,1,0,7,7,1,3,97,100,100,0,0,10,9,1,7,0,32,0,32,1,106,11,0,28,4,110,97,109,101,1,6,1,0,3,97,100,100,2,13,1,0,2,0,3,108,104,115,1,3,114,104,115]);
    
    let { 
        instance: { 
            exports: { 
                add 
            }
        }
    } = await WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes);

    console.log(add(2,3));
}
```