# Is it possible to execute a C# code/Program from Google Apps Script

Tags: c#, google-apps-script

I am totally new to Google Apps Script.

I want to have a product verification & key generation system which can recieve customers order information and issue an unique verification key file for customer to activate their product.
However, since this is a very niche market and I dont have any money to afford a server and want to make this work without my computer always on, I would like to use google sheet as a database and try to have some code to automatically this progress.

I currently finish my key generator using C# which use following package:

```
System.Text;
System.Security.Cryptography;
System.Text.RegularExpressions;
PhoneNumbers;
System.Globalization;
System.Management;
```

I am thinking to have a Google Apps Script code that embbed to Google sheets which will detect the new data added to the sheet, auto send data to my key generation program and send a email to the buyer.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't simply write your code in Google Apps Script (which appears to just be Javascript)?

Comment: Would you please summarise your research prior to asking this question. There are many precedents for integration of Google sheets and c# - it's not clear which, if any, of these you have already considered?

Comment: The google script is a java script.  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152482/running-exe-from-javascript

Comment: I want to separate my keygen program from GAS. Thats why I want to ask is it possible to call C# function from GAS?

Comment: Perhaps [this can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61190809/running-webassembly-on-google-apps-script). It wouldn't separate GAS and your C# keygen for any security purposes. Only a gated (i.e. not anonymously accessible) API would really do that and, since you said you don't want a server, you've already ruled that out.